# Sort by number of occurrences

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, scripting

What's the quickest way to sort items by number of occurrences on a Linux terminal?

Ideally, I'm looking for a one-liner.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
some_command | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: You'll probably want `sort -nr` to put the most common lines first.

Comment: @NateGlenn Depends. Usually there are pages of output so I will just `sort -r | tail -30` and the largest number is right above the new prompt. That way I don't have to worry about lines with the most hits going off the top of the screen.

Comment: And if you want to remove the item count, add a pipe to `cut -c9-` at the end.